# DNS Help? : manual BIND config attempt

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

So my domain www.jasonwarner.dev had its name servers forwarded to my unmanaged VPS provider I added the domain to my VPS with A record I can access my "site" through IP on any device but not through domain on my desktop.

The dude at hostwinds said he can pull my domain up on desktop and one out of his three coworkers could pull it up on theirs. I can bring the domain up on my phone, but not on my girlfriends phone. That was all the case before I even installed BIND and configured my dns that you see below, I have the exact same result as far as I can tell now that I have "configured" my DNS.

Telnet still tells me I have no path, and users receive a "refused request" error in their browser

Any help, hints or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Centos 7 -- Apache -- multi site set up with site enabled/available directories

[ifconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV122.png)

[etc sysconf network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGuWx.png)

[network-scripts eth0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOpVM.png)

[named conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woYq2.png)

[named conf 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhjYp.png)

[forward-zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqt3i.png)

[reverse-zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2qpz.png)

[named-status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP4xK.png)

Comment: Please add some more specific details to your post. For example, what error messages do the users who can't access your site get? What do you expect the DNS server's IP address to be? Include your zone file(s).

Comment: @fukawi2 please see my updated post entailing what you suggested I provide, I would really appreciate your thoughts or suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Answer: .dev TLD was purchased by google and google forced a strict https policy on all .dev TLD's.

My site was only loading on http, not https so I got a free ssl from letsencrypt and I am good to go